# iOS Data in List not saving value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that shows the Contacts from user contacts book. For this I am using Contacts Framework and that is working just fine.

I am showing a checkbox and a Contact Name and phone number. And just want user to select the multiple items. For this I have made a button for checkbox and changing its picture for checked and unchecked.  I have made a simple struct for this

```
struct Contacts{
 var name = ""
 var number = ""
 var isSelected = false 
 }
```

So in UiTableViewCell I am making isSelected true if it is already false and vice versa. But thing is it gets to its default false value.

What I am doing wrong?

The source (list) of UITableView is as below

```
public var listContacts : [Contacts] = []
```

and I am filling this list from Contacts Frame work. Now on user selection I dont know why this is not getting true.?

Is there any Idea what I am missing??

update1:

```
here is a code for changing value on item click or tap 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



    var selectedModel = listContacts[indexPath.row]


    selectedModel.isSelected = !selectedModel.isSelected




     print("Name ",selectedModel.name," : ",selectedModel.isSelected)



}
```

Comment: "So in UiTableViewCell I am making isSelected true if it is already false and vice versa. But thing is it gets to its default false value." showing your code should be helpful for us to solve your problem

Comment: @Siyu updated, Please check it out

Comment: do you want to save the selected cell state?

Comment: yes I want to save it state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structs are passed by **value**, when you changed the selectedModel you didn't changed the one on the listContacts but a new one. That's why the list itself didn't change.

You might consider replacing the **struct to a class**- classes are passed by **reference**